# Export the datagrid data to text in asp.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, .net-2.0

Problem:It will asks there is no assembly reference/namespace for Database

---

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
DBCommandWrapper selectCommandWrapper = 
   db.GetStoredProcCommandWrapper("sp_GetLatestArticles");
DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(selectCommandWrapper);
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

for(int i=0;i<=ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
  for(int j=0;j<=ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
  {
      str.Append(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][j].ToString());
  }

  str.Append("<BR>");
}

Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", 
         "attachment;filename=FileName.txt");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.text";

System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = 
              new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

Response.Write(str.ToString());
Response.End();
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need add a reference to the appropriate Enterprise Library DLLs. Once you've done this place the cursor over the word Database and hit "CTRL + .".

You can [download Enterprise Library here](http://www.codeplex.com/entlib).

Comment: I add the give libraries, again it asks the same error
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

Comment: You need to add this then using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data; Possible one with Common in it too...